# Training fasttext on your own corpus

Tags: python, tensorflow, word-embeddings, gensim, fasttext

I want to train fasttext on my own corpus. However, I have a small question before continuing. Do I need each sentences as a different item in corpus or can I have many sentences as one item?

For example, I have this DataFrame:

```
 text                                               |     summary
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
 this is sentence one this is sentence two continue | one two other
 other similar sentences some other                 | word word sent
```

Basically, the column `text` is an article so it has many sentences. Because of the preprocessing, I no longer have full stop `.`. So the question is can I do something like this directly or do I need to split each sentences.

```
docs = df['text']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)
```

What are the differences? Is this the right way of training fasttext in your own corpus?

Thank you!

Comment: It should give worse results if your 'sentences' are in fact very long documents and better results if you split your documents into blocks of k words where k is not too large - you might not even need to recover your lost punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

It should give worse results if your 'sentences' are in fact very long documents and better results if you split your documents into blocks of k words where k is not too large - you might not even need to recover your lost punctuation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).